# VLCJ cannot display video after pause() followed by play()

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

I'm using VLCJ for playing mp4 video in my swing application. It can play properly but when I pause() the video followed by a play() it cannot display video but it is able to resume audio. If I call stop() instead of pause() everything works fine but it starts playing from the beginning. How can I pause the video properly so that I can resume the video?

I was trying with the following class:

```
public class JVLCPlayerPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel 
{
   private File vlcPath = new File("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
   private EmbeddedMediaPlayer player;

   public JVLCPlayerPanel() {
       initComponents();

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", vlcPath.getAbsolutePath());
        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent videoCanvas = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(videoCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.player = videoCanvas.getMediaPlayer();
        this.player.setPause(true);
    }

   public void play(String media) 
   {
       player.prepareMedia(media);
       player.parseMedia();
       player.play();
   }

   public void pause() 
   {      
       player.pause();
   }

   public void resume() 
   {
       player.play();
   }
```

}

Comment: public class JVLCPlayer extends JPanel {private File vlcPath=new File("vlcpath"); private EmbeddedMediaPlayer player; public JVLCPlayer() { NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", vlcPath.getAbsolutePath()); EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent videoCanvas=new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();    setLayout(new BorderLayout()); add(videoCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER); player=videoCanvas.getMediaPlayer(); player.setPause(true);}    public void play(String media){ player.prepareMedia(media);player.parseMedia(); player.play();}    
    public void pause() {player.pause();} public void resume() {player.play();}}

Comment: I tried videoCanvas as a heap variable to the class but still the behavior is as it was earlier.

Comment: Does play/pause work properly for you in the vlcj-player project (also available on Github)?

Comment: Actually, the application has one JFrame and few JPanels; time to time one of these JPanels is attached to the contentPane of the JFrame. The JVLCPlayer panel is contained in one of the JPanels. When contentPane is getting changed with other JPanel and back to the original containing the JVLCPlayer, it cannot display the video. But if I use stop() instead of pause() it can display video after a play() call. And if I don't change the contentPane of the JFrame after attaching JPanel containing the JVLCPlayerPanel then resume works perfectly ok.Could you suggest me any workaround ?

Comment: Your last comment contains the key piece of information and should be part of your question, i.e. that you try and switch panels. This simply can not be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your post and comments, you are trying to switch a single media player component between multiple panels.

This simply does not work.

With vlcj/LibVLC the component that hosts the video surface must be "displayable" and must remain so at all times. You can not "re-parent" the video surface to another component, you can not even hide the component (you can set it to 1x1, or the best solution is to use a CardLayout, to hide it).

The reason it works when you first stop *then* play is that in this case vlcj will "re-associate" the video surface with the native media player. This can not be done while the video is playing. There's nothing you can do about it.

Probably keeping one media player per panel, and using a CardLayout, is the best solution.

Comment: I got your point but only one of the JPanels has the MediaPlayer. Other Jpanels are used for display other information. Only the contentPane of the JFrame is getting changed with different JPanels but the video surface is always attached to the same JPanel.

Comment: I don't know then. But the behaviour you describe, video disappears but audio continues, fits *exactly* with what I describe.

Comment: You say the video surface is always attached to the same panel, that is not enough. The panel itself must *always* be attached and "displayable" in the JFrame. So if you swap panels in your JFrame it will fail precisely as I described. You need to do something else like a CardLayout or a custom layout manager to achieve the affect you want.

Comment: Things are happening exactly what you explained in your last comment. From DEBUG output of VLCJ, I found componentId of the attached video surface is getting changed every time I call play() after a pause() which was happening due to switching different JPanels on contentPane of the JFrame. Instead of setting contentPane of JFrame with different JPanels time to time, now I have added these JPanels in a CardLayout and showing whichever is required. Both MediaPlayer and MediaListPlayer are working fine now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try using this code use pause() method of MediaPlayer
         and use same pause() method to play it works for me

```
           pauseButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

         mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().pause();
      });
```

Comment: I'm using EmbeddedMediaPlayer and MediaListPlayer instead of EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent. pause() method of MediaListPlayer is working fine i.e it can pause but afterward when I call play() it just resume audio but no video is getting displayed unlike stop() followed by a play()

Comment: Do you really need MediaListPlayer

Comment: I'm adding multiple media files with a MediaList and playing these in LOOP mode.

Comment: but still you can achive that using finished event when video is finished, then play the next video in the list

Comment: Actually, my application periodically polls (50 ms interval) a device for its status and as soon as it gets a specific status, it pauses the video display.The application then do some activity and update the GUI; after few moments it resumes the video display from where it left off, which may be at the mid of a specific video display, at the end or at the beginning of a specific video display. Therefore, on the basis of finished event I cannot handle the scenario. Is there any other workaround in your mind which suits the nature of my application? Thanks a lot for your responses.

Comment: i was telling to use finished event to play next video in a list and yes you can do this using MediaPlayer no need to use MediaListPlayer and  use thread or timer to do your task of updating gui

Comment: I got your point but as before even with MediaPlayer if the video is paused with pause() and then resumed with play()/pause(), only audio is resumed but no video is seen. On the other hand instead of pause if I use stop() everything works fine. I'm not really concerned about GUI update, just I needed a perfectly working pause and resume mechanism.

Comment: sorry but pause() function worked fine for me or use java fx to render videos but it will not support every video format

Comment: Actually the problem was with the video surface, it was getting changed when I swap in and swap out the JPanel containing the player in contentPane of a JFrame. MediaPlayer was working fine with pause() and also MediaListPlayer. Instead of swap-in and swap-out JPanel which was causing a change in componentId of the videosurface, this time I have used CardLayout for switching between JPanels as suggested by Caprica and the thus the problem resolved. Thanks.